# Filtered search option for off topic questions

Tags: feature-request, off-topic

I understand the reasoning behind having only the popular sites show of when voting on a post as off-topic, but wouldn't it be possible to implement a smart filtered search that normally shows the default results, but allows the user to input a search and specify exactly which site that would be recommended for this specific question?

Alternatively allow the user to input a `stack exchange` url much like the way that careers allows you to add answers beyond the top rated ones at [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). You could then add that specific option when voting is being done.

[image: careers]

Comment: Feel free to comment when down-voting. I am just trying to come up with constructive feedback to help improve the voting based moderation system. :)

Comment: I expect they were just disagreeing with your proposal and couldn't be bothered to explain why. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences.

Comment: Ah, thanks @AndrewC. I guess I am just used to stack.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying for lengthier info about meta's easy-to-interpret-as-hostile culture.

Comment: Ah no worries. I didn't take it as hostile, was more interested in knowing the reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of sites in the off-topic dialogue isn't for the most popular sites, nor even the most commonly wanted ones, but ones to which we want to send the most questions.

If you put a migration target in the close-as-duplicate dialogue, you encourage the sending of questions there, since anyone who can vote to close can participate in deciding it should be migrated.

The problem with migrating questions is that users who post a question which is off topic are ignoring the FAQ. Too frequently this means the question is not only off topic, but also non-ideal in other ways.

Stack Overflow has a huge volume of questions, and if you redirect even a small proportion of SO questions, you can swamp a smaller site. The flip side of that is you can bring a much-needed influx of questions to a site that's struggling to get going. Use with caution!

[image: close dialogue]

Notice the omission of such obvious targets as programmers, server fault, code review - they don't currently want SO's rejects.

If you allowed choosing any migration target, you would knock down the flood defences around the other sites.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks.